# Let $ f $ be a continuous function of $[0, 1]$ into itself, prove that there exists c, an element of $[0, 1]$ such that $f(c)$ = $c^2$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

"Let $ f $ be a continuous function of $[0, 1]$ into itself, prove that there exists c, an element of $[0, 1]$ such that $f(c)$ = $c^2$". It seems I need to use the intermediate value theorem for the case $f(0)\not=f(1)$ and create a function $g(x)=f(x)-x^2$ but I'm struggling to work that out into a proof, even when considering $g(0)$ and $g(1)$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In addition to the other answers, you could also look at $g(x) = \sqrt{f(x)} : [0,1] \to [0,1]$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: let $g(x)=f(x)-x^2$, $g(0)\geq 0, g(1)\leq 1$.

$g(0)=f(0)-0^2=f(0)\geq 0$ and $g(1)=f(1)-1^2\leq 0$ since $f(1)\in [0,1]$.

Comment: $g(1) = f(1)-1\leqslant 0$ actually.

Comment: @MeesdeVries It is stated that $f[0,1] \subset [0,1]$ so we do know $f(1) \leq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

$g(0)=f(0)-0\geq 0$ because range of $f$ is contained in $[0,1]$. Also $g(1)=f(1)-1\leq 0$ for the same reason. If one of these two are equalities there is nothing to prove. Otherwise intermediate value property of continuous functions tells you that $g(c)=0$ for some $c \in (0,1)$ which gives $f(c)=c^{2}$.